# SQL query many-many mapping table for data matching set of input values

Tags: sql, sql-server, many-to-many

Okay, this one gets complicated real fast.  I have a system that gathers hardware specs for a given machine.  I'm going to just focus on GPUs to keep it simple.  A machine can have any number of GPUs, and a GPU (I'm storing based on model) can exist in multiple machines.

At the top I have the MachineSpec table that contains a SpecID and a GPUConfigID (and others but we're ignoring those).  This GPUConfigID is a foreign key to the GPUConfigID in the GPU_Map table.  The GPU_Map table contains ID, GPUConfigID, and GPUID columns.  The GPUID is linked to the GPUID in the GPU table, which contains GPUID, Model, Speed, etc.

So here is an example of valid "configs" in the GPU_Map table:

[image]
What I have currently works for all cases in that table, with one caveat.  Cases like GPUConfigIDs 1 and 2 will enforce their uniqueness, so if I try to add a new config with GPUIDs 1 and 3 it won't let me (which is good).  Unfortunately, adding a duplicate GPUID within the same config (as in GPUConfigIDs 3 and 4) will register it as a completely new config despite the fact that it's identical.

It's important to note that Insertion into this table only involves GPUIDs.  Basically, I have a list of GPUIDs and I need to see if they exist as a config in the GPU_Map table.  If they do not, then create the config.  If they do, then return the GPUConfigID.

Here is the stored procedure I currently have:

```
@IDList IntList READONLY, 
@ID int OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRAN gpuconfigupdate
        DECLARE @Count INT
        SELECT @Count = (SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM GPU_Map as Map1
                LEFT OUTER JOIN @IDList as ID1
                ON Map1.GPUID = ID1.Item
            GROUP BY Map1.GPUConfigID
            HAVING COUNT(Map1.GPUID) = (SELECT COUNT(Item) FROM @IDList)
                AND COUNT(ID1.Item) = (SELECT COUNT(Item) FROM @IDList))

        IF @Count IS NULL BEGIN
            INSERT INTO GPU_Map (GPUConfigID, GPUID) 
            SELECT ((SELECT MAX(GPUConfigID) FROM GPU_Map)+1), Item FROM @IDList
        END

        SELECT @ID = (SELECT GPUConfigID 
                        FROM GPU_Map as Map1
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN @IDList as ID1
                            ON Map1.GPUID = ID1.Item
                        GROUP BY Map1.GPUConfigID
                        HAVING COUNT(Map1.GPUID) = (SELECT COUNT(Item) FROM @IDList)
                            AND COUNT(ID1.Item) = (SELECT COUNT(Item) FROM @IDList))
    COMMIT TRAN gpuconfigupdate
END
```

Also note my user-defined-type IntList:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[IntList] AS TABLE(
    [Item] [INT] NULL
);
```

NOTE:  The GPU_Map table previously had a primary key of (GPUConfigID, GPUID) but that would throw a primary key error when trying to enter a duplicate GPUID in the same config (like GPUConfigIDs 3 and 4).  That is why I created the ID column and set that as the primary key, which led me to my current situation.

Comment: When you are doing a count of rows on a query, it will return 0 even if no rows are found. Therefore, you should change your condition to check the @count for 0 instead of null. If this does not solve your problem, post a screenshot of your ER diagram that shows the relations between these tables.

Comment: I'm not sure that's true because that "IF @Count IS NULL" handles the INSERT which is currently happening.  The problem is that it's inserting when it shouldn't be, so something with the SELECT statement above it is not catching the case I described in the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People from the future, rejoice!  For I have managed to figure out a solution to this problem.

The query in question was this one:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM GPU_Map as Map1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN @IDList as ID1
        ON Map1.GPUID = ID1.Item
    GROUP BY Map1.GPUConfigID
    HAVING COUNT(Map1.GPUID) = (SELECT COUNT(Item) FROM @IDList)
        AND COUNT(ID1.Item) = (SELECT COUNT(Item) FROM @IDList)
```

It was working as intended with the exception of cases where @IDList contained duplicate values (which is valid).  The solution was to change the last two lines to this:

```
    HAVING COUNT(Map1.RAMID) = COUNT(ID1.Item)
        AND COUNT(DISTINCT ID1.Item) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Item) FROM @IDList))
```

Note that the last two lines of the stored procedure in the OP before the COMMIT will also need to be changed in the same way.